# UISearchDisplayController searchResultsTableView not hiding in iOS7

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios7, xcode5

I am using UISearchDisplayController for displaying search result in tableview. If the search result is empty i am hiding the UISearchDisplaycontroller's searchResultTableView. Its working fine till iOS 6.0 but not in iOS 7.
I am working around to find some solution but unfortunately i didn't find it yet. 
I am using following statement to hide the searchResultTableView

> self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView.hidden= YES;

Following are the screen shots as in iOS 6 and iOS 7.

[image][image]

Edited :

I am using following UISearchDisplayController delegate methods

```
-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller
shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
 [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString
                           scope:[[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles]
                                  objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar
                                                 selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];
return YES;
}


-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller
 shouldReloadTableForSearchScope:(NSInteger)searchOption 
  {
[self filterContentForSearchText:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar text]
                           scope:[[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles]
                                  objectAtIndex:searchOption]];
return YES; 
}


-(void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString *)searchText scope:(NSString *)scope{
[Appdelegate.arrFilteredDrugSummary removeAllObjects];
[Appdelegate.arrFilteredDrugID removeAllObjects];

for (DrugDetails *drug in Appdelegate.arrDrugSummary)
{
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
                              @"(SELF BEGINSWITH [cd] %@)", searchText];
    if(![drug.tradeName isEqual:[NSNull null]])
    {
        [drug.tradeName compare:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
        BOOL resultTradeName; 
        if((resultTradeName = [predicate evaluateWithObject:drug.tradeName]))
        {
            if (![Appdelegate.arrFilteredDrugID containsObject:drug.ID])
            {
                [Appdelegate.arrFilteredDrugSummary addObject:drug];
                [Appdelegate.arrFilteredDrugID addObject:drug.ID];
            }
        }
    }
}
if (![Appdelegate.arrFilteredDrugSummary count])
{
    [self.btnAddNewDrug setHidden:NO];
    self.tblview.hidden=YES;
    self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView.hidden = YES;
}
else
{
    [self.btnAddNewDrug setHidden:YES];
    self.tblview.hidden=NO;
    self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView.hidden = NO;
}
[self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: Where are you calling that line of code? You might want to try moving it to `searchDisplayController:didShowSearchResultsTableView:` if you haven't already had it there. BTW...I was running into so many issues with UISearchDisplayController on iOS 7 that I just stripped it out completely and wrote the custom code required to do the job and interact with the UISearchBar without it.

Comment: @smileyborg : i have edited my question above and added the code where i have implemented the code for hidding the searchResultTableView. Will you please suggest me where i'm going wrong.

Comment: @smileyborg : i added the searchDisplayController:didShowSearchResultsTableView:  method as suggested by you. it solved by issue, but ran into another issue. I'm not getting click event for the "Don't see it? Ask us!" button in iOS 7.

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing this same problem . You can overcome from it by this way

```
- (void)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller didShowSearchResultsTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView.hidden = YES;
}
```

If any result find Then use this code to dismiss searchDisplayController

```
if (yourArray.count != 0) 
{
     // reload your table here
     [self.searchDisplayController setActive:NO animated:YES];
     self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView.hidden = YES;
}
```

> **OR**

If search result find , You can hide searchDisplayController via use this code

```
[self searchBarCancelButtonClicked:searchBar];
```

It would call UISearchBar searchBarCancelButtonClicked delegate and

```
- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)_searchBar {

    if (yourArray.count == 0) {
        self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView.hidden = YES;
    }
    else
    {
        self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView.hidden = NO;
    }
}
```

I hope it will help you...!

Comment: Thanks Chandan for your reply..! Does it work fine on iOS7. Actually I was unable to resolve the issue, so I removed UISearchDisplayController and implemented UISearchBar Delegate methods to accomplish my task. I'll definitely try it out as suggested by you.

Comment: Sorry for late reply but i faced this problem right now. and Yes Mahesh, It is working perfectly here. And if you are using UISearch Bar then you can force fully call cancel searchBarCancelButtonClicked degegate and perform whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

you know if the searchbar has focus.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if ([_searchBar isFirstResponder]) {
              return [_filteredData count];
    } else {

        id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
        return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];

    }
}
```

When configuring the cell do the same question

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomCell";
    CustomTableViewCell *cell = (CustomTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    // Configure the cell...
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[CustomTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    Entidad *e = nil;

    if ([_searchBar isFirstResponder])
    {
        e = [self.filteredData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    }
    else
    {
        e = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    }

    cell.nameLabel.text = e.titulo;
    cell.thumbnailImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"password-50.png"];
    cell.dateLabel.text = e.sitio;

    return cell;
}
```

Set the filter parameters

```
-(void)filter:(NSString*)text
{

    _filteredData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];


    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
                                   entityForName:@"Entidad" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];


    NSSortDescriptor* sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
                                        initWithKey:@"titulo" ascending:YES];
    NSArray* sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];


    if(text.length > 0)
    {

        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(titulo CONTAINS[c] %@)", text];
        [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
    }

    NSError *error;


    NSArray* loadedEntities = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    _filteredData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:loadedEntities];

    NSLog(@"%@", _filteredData);

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar*)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString*)text
{
    [self filter:text];
}

-(void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar{

    [self filter:@""];

    [_searchBar resignFirstResponder];
    [_searchBar setText:@""];
    [_tableView reloadData];
}

- (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{

    [_searchBar setShowsCancelButton:YES animated:YES];
}

-(void)searchBarTextDidEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    [_searchBar setShowsCancelButton:NO animated:YES];
}
```

I hope to serve you, my English is very limited